# How can I force VSCode to use a specific terminal when I click run/debug from the GUI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

So, I have multiple terminals open in the VSCode editor. I want the VSCode to use a specific terminal that I have named as `interactive`. Is it possible for me to force VSCode to use that terminal and not the default terminal?

### More details

I am trying to run python programs on a cluster that uses lsf scheduler. I have created a remote session in VSCode to the login node of the cluster. Hence, the default terminal of VSCode would run programs on the login node which is not allowed.
In another integrated terminal, I have created an interactive session using the scheduler to a compute node. I am trying to force VSCode to use this terminal.